# "Использовать" или "пользовать"?

Tags: значение-слов

Пожалуйста, объясните разницу между этим словами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Пользовать"* в том смысле, в котором вы, очевидно, его употребили, в словаре нету. Это современный сленг, на мой взгляд, просто коверкание слова *"использовать".* Явление, похожее на то, что вчера услышал в магазине от покупателя: *"поло́жил".* Аналогично не могу оправдать нынче модное слово, кальку с английского, *"юзать"* — лучше уж *"пользовать".* Зачем? Есть же русское слово. Эти два других не привносят никакого нового нюанса смысла даже.

У слова *"пользовать"* есть [другое](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) устаревшее значение: *лечить.*